# Code does not display error message when user puts in an incorrect angle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a projectile motion simulator and would like to display an error message when the user inputs an angle that isn't between 0 and 90 degrees, but the text never displays

```
var calculate = function() {        
    var velocity = parseFloat(ctx.getElementById('Velocity').value);
    var angle = parseFloat(ctx.getElementById('Angle').value);
    var initialHeight = parseFloat(ctx.getElementById('Height').value) || 0;
    var vertPlane = parseFloat(ctx.getElementById('Vertical').value);
    var landPlane =  parseFloat(ctx.getElementById('Final-Height').value) || 0;

    if (angle > 90 || angle < 0 || angle === undefined) {
        ctx.restore();
        ctx.save();
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillText("Please pick an angle between 0 and 90 degrees", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
        ctx.translate(0, canvas.height);
        ctx.scale(1, -1);

    }
}
```

The rest of the code can be found here https://jsfiddle.net/xk22k8s7/1/

Comment: Is that the only thing that doesn't work? Or does nothing work altogether? (Hint: `ctx.getElementById` makes no sense, and you actually get an error message, just look at your console)

Comment: `ctx.getElementById('Velocity').value` and the like don't make sense. the elements you are tying to read are not part of `ctx` they are part of `document`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments were correct, the issue was that i was using `ctx.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementById`because those input fields are not in the context, they are in the document.